# SQL Server and Powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I tried to run this script:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

$url = "http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml"

$file = "C:\Sharon\newnewnew777.xml"

$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)
```

In powershell it runs fine, but when I try to run it as a job in SQL Server it give me the following error:

> A job step received an error at line 5 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is
>       ''$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)''    . Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: ''Exception calling 
>       "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): 
>   "An exception occurred during a     WebClient request."  ''.  Process Exit Code -1.  The step failed.'

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: make sure the location of your file exists on the server

Comment: Also check the rights/permissions of the account that the job is running under from SQL.

Comment: Many times Servers are not allowed to browse to the internet (either via Firewall or Proxy rules), or the Service ID might not be allowed to authenticate through the proxy.  So outside of local permissions, make sure to check network permissions as well.

Comment: Thank's! I think I will do it via the task scheduler.